# SELinux policy issue

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, lighttpd, selinux

As qemu & KVM are working fine with SELinux out of the box I'd like to enable SELinux to improve guest isolation on my CentOS 6 server. The problem is that I'm using a 3rd parity virtualization managment software that requires SELinux to be disabled. As they will never implement that I'm now trying to get this working on my own...

While I was able to fix all libvirt/qemu related issues (changing default image/lvm location and fixing another issue with audit2allow) I got stuck with the custom **lighttpd** they're using to process various managment tasks.

I tried to add a custom rule with audit2allow but that didn't work at all. So as I'm not a SELinux expert I'm just looking for a way to

- **just put lighttpd in permissive mode (so it can do whatever neccessary)**
- **enforce SELinux only for the qemu/libvirt processes running the VMs**

I already found this in the semanage manpage and I think that it might be a solution
    `semanage permissive -a TYPE http_r` command
but this just returns: */usr/sbin/semanage: bad option*

I assume this is because they're not running the stock lighttpd from the CentOS repo and so the policy for lighty is missing.

Here's a short snippet from the audit.log

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1393761691.786:1259): arch=c000003e syscall=9
success=yes exit=140369999609856 a0=0 a1=1fa588 a2=5 a3=802 items=0
ppid=1 pid=8532 auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500
fsuid=500 egid=500 sgid=500 fsgid=500 tty=(none) ses=4294967295
comm="php" exe="/usr/bin/php" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
key=(null) type=AVC msg=audit(1393761691.813:1260): avc:  denied  {
name_connect } for  pid=8532 comm="php" dest=5656
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
tcontext=system_u:object_r:port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket type=SYSCALL
msg=audit(1393761691.813:1260): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no
exit=-115 a0=4 a1=7fffa6ed55f0 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=8532
auid=4294967295 uid=500 gid=500 euid=500 suid=500 fsuid=500 egid=500
sgid=500 fsgid=500 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php"
exe="/usr/bin/php" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1393761691.969:1261): avc:  denied  { nlmsg_write }
for  pid=8552 comm="tc" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_route_socket
```

Comment: what 3rd party solution specifically requires disabling SEL?

Comment: SolusVM. While the software is quite ok those guys don't have security in mind. Once we've had an issue with node-syncing their support disabled the whole firewall to "fix" the problem ...

Comment: why use them then? There's perfectly good oVirt and proxmox available, and if you need support, what can be better than RHEV?

Comment: Well, that's good to hear. Now I can strike SolusVM off my shopping list.

Comment: Well it isn't *that* bad after all. You just have to take care of some security aspects (SELinux ^^) yourself. Some other popular products (like cPanel) don't work with SELinux either.
I think I might give oVirt a try somewhen in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```